# Python requests.json keeps giving errors

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to get the current location of International Space Station(ISS) and display it in a json format.
The code seems okay but I keep getting error and I don't know why.

```
import requests

sample = requests.get(url="http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/ISS-Location-Now/")

conv= sample.json()
print(conv)
```

I was expecting the code to return a json of the current location of the ISS but I kept getting this error instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guest\PycharmProjects\Api\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    conv = sample.json()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: `http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/ISS-Location-Now/` is a normal HTML website, not JSON. Use the first API URL documented on that site instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [documentation](http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/ISS-Location-Now/) link, not the actual API link;
http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json

---

So the code becomes:

```py
import requests

sample = requests.get(url="http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")

conv= sample.json()
print(conv)
```

Printing:

```json
{'iss_position': {'longitude': '-97.8479', 'latitude': '16.1262'}, 'message': 'success', 'timestamp': 1701706077}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've corrected the mistake and its working now. Really appreciate it